# How does software that extracts or views EXIF work?

Tags: software, metadata, file-format

I'm currently doing a research project on metadata extraction from various filetypes, and I'm not able to find any documents or research papers on image metadata extraction from photos. All I can find are tools. I'm interested in knowing how the tools which view and display the metadata of images *work*.

Comment: The metadata is stored in the file. The tool reads the metadata. What more is there to say?

Comment: http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf

Comment: Yea, I think you need to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: why would any research paper tell this? Research is about creating knowledge, not explain how to read known knowledge from a well defined known protocol. Just look up the protocol. Simple as that. http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about most probably programming.

Comment: Also, many of those tools are open-source, meaning you're free to inspect how they work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you are envisioning that the information displayed by metadata viewers  is extracted by analyzing the image in some way, creating descriptive information from the pixels which make up the image. That's not the case. It's written to the files by the digital cameras (or scanners) that create them, according to several standards, including the [EXIF](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf) you mentioned, as well as [IPTC](http://www.iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata) and [XMP](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xmp/sdk/XMPspecification.pdf).

The file formats which support metadata include standard ways to embed this information. Software meant for dealing with digital image files generally includes support for reading and writing these file formats according to their standards, and the metadata within according to *those* various standards.

If you are a programmer, you can browse the [exiv2 source code online](http://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/repository), which may give you an idea of how it's done. As I've explained, it's relatively straightforward in theory, but as you can see from the source, all of the different formats do add up to significant complication.

If you are writing your own software, you probably don't want to deal with all of that — instead, take advantage of the fact that other people already have. You can use the open source exiv2 library in your project — [the API is documented here](http://www.exiv2.org/doc/index.html).